# Jquery web service request for IE7 > and Safari

Tags: jquery, json, web-services

I'm using a Web Service with JQuery, the response is JSON format. I've developed the request for Chrome and Firefox and it works fine but IExplorer 7> and Safari doesn't work. I've search and I have not seen any usefull way to do it works.
Do you have any idea how to solve the problem?
here is my code:

```
// To Know if browser is chrome
var chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

//Set client ID
var ID = "ABC123";

$.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.../generateSession',
            data: "id=" + ID,

            beforeSend: function( xhr ){
                //Show waiting div
            },

            success: function( data ) {


                if (console && console.log){
                    var json = null;
                // if browser is chrome, then use parseJSON 
                if(!chrome) {
                        json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    } else {
                        json = data;
                    }

            sessionStorage.setItem("SID", json.sessionId);
            console.info("Fetched session id " + json.sessionId)
            // … hide waiting div
} ///Session created
    }, error : function() { 
                alert("Error, please try again");
            }

        });     
}
```

Comment: I have same problem but it occurs in safari..anyone has solution??